# html dom native array of form content

Tags: html, forms, dom

I think this is a really simple question and I imagine it is a duplicate, but many Google searches and stackoverflow searches are all coming up blank.

If I have a form:

```
<form name="myForm">
    Data1: <input type='text' name='num1'>
    Data2: <input type='text' name='num2'>
    Data3: <input type='checkbox' name='num1'>
</form>
```

And I want to get the full content in some native dom array like:

```
document.myForm.allofthecontent
```

Is there some such native dom element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `document.forms['myForm']`. This is a [`HTMLFormElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) object which will contain the standard element properties, as well as some extra methods and properties relating to forms.

It also acts as a zero-indexed array containing the input elements within the form.

[Here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/cmtgl9ym) is a demonstration of one way you could utilise this.

```
var f = document.forms['myForm'];
for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
    console.log(f[i].type.match(/checkbox|radio/) ? f[i].checked : f[i].value);
    //do something with the element's value
}
```

Depending on the type of the element, you may need to get the value using something other than merely `value` or `checked`.

**Edit**: As mentioned in the comments, I don't know of a native function that will do what you wish, so don't be afraid to write your own function.

[Here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/hkri3nfq) is a demonstration of a function that returns the form elements' values in an array.

```
function getFormValues(form) {
    var ret = [ ];
    for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
        switch (form[i].type) {
            case 'checkbox':
            case 'radio':
                ret.push(form[i].checked);
                break;
            default:
                ret.push(form[i].value);
                break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = function() {
        console.log(getFormValues(document.forms['myForm']));
    };
};
```

I began making it return the values as an associative array (an object, really) but I realised that if you need that, you may as well be selecting them by name in the first place.

Comment: I believe that document.forms['myForm'] is identical to document.myForm.  It is a great way to access the data, but I am hoping to get an array with the data.  I am using firebug and typing into the console, but it would be the same as using javascript and storing it into a variable as far as I know.

Comment: @Thomas I don't know of a native function that would do what you want.

Comment: @Thomas I have edited my answer. What do you want this blob of content for anyway?

Comment: This really is just an open DOM question.  I know enough JavaScript to go through the HTMLCollections, though your code above is still useful as I consider my approach.  Your response regarding `document.forms['myForms']` and the response by j08691 regarding `document.myForm.elements` are both appreciated.  I think I will wait a few hours before I close it by accepting a response to see if any other thoughts are offered.

Comment: @Thomas But what do you want the data for? What meaning does the data have without the input fields' `name`s associated with the respective value? Do you intend to use this for form validation?

Answer (score 0):

`document.myForm.elements` will return a collection of all the form elements that you can loop through.

```
var elems = document.myForm.elements;
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    console.log(elems[i].value);
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5CnEu/)**

Comment: I am looking at that one in firebug.  It appears to have all the "property values" and "attribute values" which is good.  Are there any others I should consider that might have "names"?

Comment: `elems[i].name` should have the name attribute.

Comment: Looking into it further, `.elements` is an HTMLCollection, not an array.  So, what I am getting from your answer is: "No, there is no native DOM property which has an array of the 'property values', however, it is easy enough to use `.elements' and extract the data into an array".  Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. The collection returned is array-like and should give you what you need.